# Best option to search for characters in a column using R

Tags: r, regex

I have a df with column which contains different codes (ICD-10). The column contains codes which consists of 4 alpha numeric characters. I want to search for specific codes based on just the first two characters. For example if this is the column

```
codes = c("s001", "s1234", "s4g6", "T002", "T191","t985","s761","t17.5")
```

and I want all those rows where it contains `S0, S1, T0, T9, T1` and assign it one and 0 if not present. I previously have used %like% with case_when. However, I would like to know if there an efficient way to do this in R.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl()` to test for a regular expression and return true for any string that starts with s0, s1, T0, T1, T9 and otherwise false. Then `ifelse()` to take that vector of TRUEs and FALSEs and assigned 1 for the TRUEs, otherwise 0.

```
codes <- c("s001", "s1234", "s4g6", "T002", "T191","t985","s761","t17.5")

ifelse(grepl("^s[01]|^T[019]", codes), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Can also do:

```
as.numeric(grepl("^s[01]|^T[019]", codes))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I use ifelse(grepl("^s[01234]"), if I am searching for S0,S1,S2,S3,S4 ?

Comment: Yes, or "^s[0-4]" for more efficiency

Answer (score 2):

We could define a pattern you want to detect and then use `str_detect` and assign 1 to TRUE and 0 to FALSE:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# your dataframe with codes column
df <- data.frame(codes = c("s001", "s1234", "s4g6", 
                              "T002", "T191","t985",
                              "s761","t17.5"))

# define what you want to search for
search_pattern <- "S0|S1|T0|T9|T1"

# check with `str_detect`
df %>% 
    mutate(check = ifelse(str_detect(df$codes, search_pattern)==TRUE, 1, 0))
```

Output:

```
  codes check
1  s001     0
2 s1234     0
3  s4g6     0
4  T002     1
5  T191     1
6  t985     0
7  s761     0
8 t17.5     0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
+(grepl("^s[01]|^T[019]", codes))
[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `grepl`

```
> +grepl("^([sT][01]|T9)", codes)
[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the substring approach. Extract only first 2 characters from the `codes` using `substr` and compare it against the `correct_values`.

```
codes = c("s001", "s1234", "s4g6", "T002", "T191","t985","s761","t17.5")

correct_values <- c("s0", "s1", "T0", "T9", "T1")

as.integer(substr(codes, 1, 2) %in% correct_values)
#[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
```